# Simple Swing Delay

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

In a swing application, I have a popup jDialog which pops up with a jlabel that says "Hang on 5 seconds."

After 5 Seconds, the label should change to "Okay, now I'm done."  And a button should appear allowing the user to click continue.

In the example action below (linked to a button which causes the popup), the popup appears as it should but it is blank instead of saying "Hang on 5 seconds."  Then after 5 seconds everything updates and the labels are there and the button too.  So what's going on?  Is the thread sleeping before a repaint or something?

```
@Action
    public void popUp() {
        popUpDialog.setSize(300,200);
        popUpDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        popUpDialog.setVisible(true);

        popUpLabel.setVisible(true);
        popUpLabel.setText("Working, hang on a sec....");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        popUpLabel.setText("Okay Now I'm Done.");
        popUpBut.setVisible(true);
    }
```

EDIT: So I tried this, in an effort to use a swing timer in place of thread sleeping:

```
@Action
        public void popUp() {
            popUpDialog.setSize(300,200);
            popUpDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            popUpDialog.setVisible(true);

            popUpLabel.setVisible(true);
            popUpLabel.setText("Working, hang on a sec....");

            Timer timer = new Timer(speed, this);
            timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
            timer.start(); 

            popUpLabel.setText("Okay Now I'm Done.");
            popUpBut.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Obviously I'll need more code to finish the timer, but right off the bat I get a `symbol not found, variable: timer` error.  What's that all about?  Am I doing it wrong?

Edit 2:  I changed the timer declaration and solved one problem but created another.  Now I am getting the symbol not found error in regards to `speed`.  I have never used a swing timer before and don't know how to use them.  The java tutorial on the topic is convoluted and difficult to understand.  Can any of you point me to a simple, clear example of a timer so I can learn from that and figure out what I need to do?

Comment: there must be two swing timers (really one with two states)

Comment: Is popUp() being executed on the EDT? No painting of "Working, hang on a sec...." is going to be done if you set the text, freeze the EDT for 5 seconds, then change the text to something else all before it repaints. You should use another timing mechanism too, like a Swing Timer.

Comment: I think you're right about it sleeping before it paints.  Have you tried inserting a `repaint()` right before you sleep?

Comment: I thought all swing apps were on a single thread?  So yes?  can I just force a repaint before the wait?

Comment: I tried adding the line `repaint();` just before the try, but the IDE says cannot find symbol.

Comment: try it :) (I'm not 100% sure if it will do it, but it looks to me like that should fix it even if it's not the optimal way of doing things.)

Comment: I think you need to call the repaint on an object -- probably either the label or the dialog would work.  try `popUpLabel.repaint()` or `popUpDialog.repaint()`

Comment: Calling it on both the label and the dialog had no effect.

Comment: how about moving the setVisible to after the setText?  (Sorry, I tend to have a bit of a trial-and-error approach to Swing, rather than really knowing what's going on, which is obviously non-optimal, but usually does get the job done.)

Comment: To my first comment, if you are calling repaint() and your code modifying your Swing component's state is on the EDT here (you should be), then no repaint will happen until your EDT code here ends, and until all other EDT requests queued before the last repaint are completed. So yes, Swing is single threaded, and does one action at a time, and if this code is on the EDT (it should be), then it's impossible for the same thread to be executing a repaint at the same time. This is another reason why you should use a Swing Timer, sleeping won't work no matter what if your Swing code is threadsafe.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove what you say makes sense.  So is there a simple way to do what the OP wants, without changing to a Swing Timer?

Comment: Swing Timer is the best option because the events occur on the EDT, but really he could use any timing mechanism, even shooting off another thread here and then sleeping on that, while also calling repaint here. But doing that manual thread work is not needed, it's already coded for you (Swing Timer).

Comment: `The java tutorial on the topic is convoluted and difficult to understand.` then search the forum or the web for other examples. We don't know what you find confusing about the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code modifying your Swing component's state is on the EDT here (it should be), then no repainting of the label with the first text will take place even if you do call repaint(), because all other EDT requests queued before the last repaint need to complete before you reach that repaint, and your code here is one of those queued EDT events.

If you call repaint, it adds a repaint to the queue, it doesn't repaint right away. Your actions here will result in a 5 second wait, with the label before the next repaint having only the text you last set it to (as code queued on the EDT is executed fully before going to what next is queued).

Try using a Swing Timer, events fired from the Swing Timer are already executing on the EDT, so it's pretty much what you need, one event here where you set the text initially, and another event fired by the Swing Timer to change the text after 5 seconds.

Edit, example of Swing Timer firing once, after 5 seconds as requested by author:

```
    // set first jlabel text here

    ActionListener task = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("This is on the EDT after 5 seconds, " +
                "well depending on if I'm used with a Timer, and if " +
                "the right options are set to that Timer");
            // set second jlabel text here
        }
        };
    Timer timer = new Timer(5000 , task);
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
```

Comment: As I added in my second edit: could you point out an example of a simple, clear swing timer so I can figure out how to use it?  The java tuts one is quite confusing.

Comment: Sure, posted. Make sure you import javax.swing.Timer and not java.util.Timer accidentally.

Comment: I wish this was the java tutorial example.  THIS I understand.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Np. If you want a good book on Swing I'd recommend the book Filthy Rich Clients. Also sometimes the javadocs for various classes have pretty good quick use cases, if you check the one for Swing Timer, you'll see it has a quick use case that's essentially what I posted, pretty handy to check there sometimes too. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have a popup jDialog which pops up with a jlabel that says "Hang on 5 seconds."

You have a dialog that is visible BEFORE:

1. you set the text on the label
2. the Thread.sleep()

The code following popupDialog.setVisible(true) is not executed until the dialog is closed. Reorder your code.

Also, you need to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the changing of the text.

Comment: Reorder it how?  Also I tried adding `timer = new Timer(speed, this);` etc in place of the try block, but the IDE just says "cannot find symbol Variable: timer"

Comment: By really just changing the order in your code. setVisible should be the last method you call ;)

Comment: you want `Timer timer = new Timer(speed, this);` I think to get rid of the compile error

Comment: @fildred13, you need to add the code to change the label BEFORE you make the dialog visible. And you need to start the Timer BEFORE you make the dialog visible.`

Answer (score 0):

```
       popUpLabel.setVisible(true);
       popUpLabel.setText("Working, hang on a sec....");
```

should be

```
       popUpLabel.setText("Working, hang on a sec....");
       popUpLabel.setVisible(true);
```

and AFTER this you should set the dialog to visible.

You could also keep the order of your code as you have it now - and force the label / panel to update. Though this seems like less of a logical choice in this scenario

Comment: I tried this.  It resulted in the same outcome: blank screen for 5 seconds, then the changed label and button appeared.